# sharepoint custom workflow by visual studio

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

i wanted to know if it possible to create a workflow in visual studio for a form library to make approval for forms by manager and if it possible how ,and if it possible to make a certain code inside it because i need to insert specific code

Comment: Yes you can. But like what @SteveB said what have you tired?

Comment: i  created a new squential workflow for the library but i need now to make a status for the forms to make manager only can edit it for approval or rejecting can you please tell me where to start

Comment: i created a workflow by using share point designer and assigned the form to specefic group but i want to know how to insert code inside the workflow or to make that workflow approved by manager as approved or rejected or pending and to make the employee see that reply